# Best way to use checkboxes inside a Extjs Pivot Grid

Tags: extjs, extjs6, pivot-grid

I have a pivot grid which display if the users have create,read,update,delete" permissions, the users are agrouped in this way departaments > estabilishments > sectors > users and i want the user to be able to edit this fields.

I already tried using with a renderer:

```
aggregate: [{
    renderer: function(value, record, dataIndex, cell, column) {
        var id = Ext.id();
        Ext.defer(function() {
            Ext.widget('checkbox', {
                renderTo: id,
                checked: value,
                listeners: {
                    change: {
                        fn: function(event, target) {
                            //some function here
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        }, 100);
        return Ext.String.format('<div id="{0}"></div>', id);
    },
    aggregator: 'aggCheckBoxR',
    dataIndex: 'Incluir',
    header: 'Incluir'
}]
```

and with a widget column:

```
aggregate: [{
    aggregator: 'aggCheckBoxR',
    column: {
        xtype: 'widgetcolumn',
        widget: {
            xtype: 'checkbox',
            listeners: {
                change: function(cb) {
                        //some function here
                }
            }
        }
    },
    dataIndex: 'Incluir',
    header: 'Incluir'
}]
```

My Aggregator:

```
aggCheckBoxR: function(records, measure, matrix, rowGroupKey, colGroupKey) {
    if (records.length > 1) {
        let checkAllTrue = true;
        for (var i = 0; i < records.length; i++) {
            if (records[i].get('Incluir') === false || records[i].get('Incluir') === 0) {
                checkAllTrue = false;
            }
        }
        return checkAllTrue;
    } else {
        return records[0].get('Incluir');
    }
}
```

The checkbox apears on the grid but my problem is the data "dont persist", whenever i expand or collapse a left axis on the pivot grid the value of the checkbox returns to its original value, how can i persist this data?

Already tried update the record manualy

```
change: function(cb) {
    var nomeCmp = cb.getWidgetRecord().data._compactview_;
    Ext.getStore('acesso.ColabStore').findRecord('Nome', nomeCmp).data.Incluir = true;
}
```

But still, it doestn't work.

**EDIT**: Had to change the column object event listener to:

```
{
    xtype: 'widgetcolumn',
    widget: {
        xtype: 'checkbox',
        listeners: {
            afterrender: function(component, eOpts) {
                console.log('after,render');
                component.getEl().on('change', function(e, el) {
                    console.log('change func here');
                })
            }
        }
    }
}
```

With this, the change event is only fired when the users check a checkbox, and finally, I could use 
[norbeq's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4340950/norbeq) answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update the record manually using:

`record.set('Incluir',true);`

and if you dont wan't to send changes to server:

`record.commit();`

Comment: this record, is the record from the pivot grid store, or from the widgetrecord? because the widgetrecord dont have 'Incluir' or other values, only 'c1,c2,c3...'

Comment: I'm almost getting the desired result, but the change event of the checkbox is being fired twice, how can I prevent the second one from being fired?

Comment: So maybe you should execute only `commit` in change listener. Can you attach the code in fiddle ?

Comment: Don't know what to do, just expanding and collapsing a leftaxis fires the change event of the checkboxes, I want to make a POST request to my backend when the user check the boxes, it seems when it renders the checkbox it fires the change event, i need a click event or something, so it'll be fired just when the user click on a checkbox

Comment: Which attached code i don't know how you communicate with your backend. You can use `Ext.Ajax` or `store.sync` in change event.

Comment: I will make an ajax call, the problem isn't making the call, but the change event being fired when the checkbox is rendered on the grid, how can I know the difference in the event, if it was an actual click or just rendered?

Comment: Had to change the event listeners to afterrender and then get the element and set event onchange on the element, updated the question to illustrate this.